# SQL Server : each group by expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference -On Turk colition

Tags: sql-server-2008

I get this error

> *each group by expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference*

I am inserting date into a temp table, and error is at the following group by query(only on some collation)

```
insert into @Temp(Name, ID)
   select 
      USR.Name,
      ISNULL((SELECT SUM(BCR.QUANTITY) 
              FROM Rate BCR            
              WHERE BCR.RateID = USR.RateID 
              GROUP BY USR.RateID), 0) AS TotalQuantity
   from 
      dbo.User as USR
   where 
      USR.Status = 1
```

Comment: Marc_s - Thanks for the formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a correlated sub query where USR.RateID is from the outer query. Since you are using USR.RateID in the where clause you can remove the GROUP BY clause since there will only ever be one value for USR.RateID for each invocation of the sub query.

```
insert into @Temp(Name, ID)
   select 
      USR.Name,
      ISNULL((SELECT SUM(BCR.QUANTITY) 
              FROM Rate BCR            
              WHERE BCR.RateID = USR.RateID), 0) AS TotalQuantity
   from 
      dbo.User as USR
   where 
      USR.Status = 1
```

Comment: Mikael Eriksson - Many Thanks for your reply, i will just try out this solution which makes sense. Ill mark the answer once i am sure this works. Thanks buddy.

Comment: I cannot add a answer since my reputation points are less, so could you please edit your comment and add my explanation as well. Thanks

Comment: @Zodiac Sorry, I don't understand. What explanation should I add where?

Comment: Mikael - query can also work with group by clause, just have to use GROUP BY BCR.RateID instead of USR.RateID.   insert into @Temp(Name, ID)
   select 
      USR.Name,
      ISNULL((SELECT SUM(BCR.QUANTITY) 
              FROM Rate BCR            
              WHERE BCR.RateID = USR.RateID 
              GROUP BY BCR.RateID), 0) AS TotalQuantity
   from 
      dbo.User as USR
   where 
      USR.Status = 1